# Calculate CDF of a log normal distribution knowing mean and mode

Tags: python, simpy, cumulative-distribution-function

I know that a distribution is a log normal with mean = 4744 and mode = 3777. I need to calculate the probability of X being lower than the mean.

In order to do so I need to calculate the CDF of my log normal distribution, and I know that I need to calculate the standard deviation to have the CDF. The problem is that I don't know how to get the standard deviation knowing the mean and the mode. I know what is the formulas of mean, standard deviation and mode, from these three I can substitute and reach the formula to get the standard deviation from the mode and the mean but I am not able to solve it.

I tried with simpy and this is the code, but when I try to run it python gets stucked:

```
x = symbols('x')

mode = 3777
mean = 4744

expr = mode -np.e**(mean - x)


sol = solve(expr)
```

Any idea or suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: When you say you get stuck, can you please show what you mean? If you get an error, please paste it in here. If you get a result, but you're expecting a different result, please present both the result you get, and what you would expect to get instead.

Comment: Does this help[How to Calculate & Plot a CDF in Python](https://www.statology.org/cdf-python/)

Comment: sorry with "get stuck" I meant that it never finishes running and basically it crashes.

Comment: @itprorh66 thanks for answering, but the problem is not that I don't know how to calculate the CDF or PDF of the function, the problem is that I need to calculate the standard deviation before being able to calculate the PDF or CDF and I don't know how to calculate the standard deviation knowing mean and mode.

Comment: Can't you use np.std???